# Pivot/unstack a DataFrame with duplicate entries without aggregation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I got a DataFrame as follow:

```
        Col_0 Col_1
Index_1        
      A     0     2
      A     3     1
      A     2     2
      B     3     1
      B     4     3
      B     5     1
```

And I would like to reshape to it into following format:

```
    Col_0     Col_1
    A    B    A    B
    0    3    2    1
    3    4    1    3
    2    5    2    1
```

I've try `pandas.pivot`, `pandas.unstack`, `pandas.groupby`. None of it worked. Can anyone help me out with it? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the index with `cumcount` then `pivot`:

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby(df.index).cumcount()
df.reset_index().pivot(index='idx', columns='Index_1').rename_axis(None)
```

Output:

```
        Col_0    Col_1   
Index_1     A  B     A  B
0           0  3     2  1
1           3  4     1  3
2           2  5     2  1
```